# Composer requiring another package from a private package results in conflicts

Tags: php, composer-php

I maintain multiple repositories which share a lot of code. So I created this 1 private composer package to avoid having code duplication throughout these repositories. Right now I am adding some code that wraps around the Mollie SDK. In my mind it's very obvious as this package uses the Mollie SDK it is the one that will have to do the composer require.

The composer setup looks like this:

```
repository A ---requires---> private/package ---requires---> Mollie
```

When I run: `composer update private/package` in the root of repository A I get the following error:

```
Problem 1
    - *private/package* dev-master requires mollie/mollie-api-php ^2.0 -> satisfiable by mollie/mollie-api-php[v2.0.0, v2.0.0-beta-1, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - *private/package* dev-master requires mollie/mollie-api-php ^2.0 -> satisfiable by mollie/mollie-api-php[v2.0.0, v2.0.0-beta-1, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for *private/package* dev-master@dev -> satisfiable by *private/package*[dev-master].
```

I tried adding `minimum-stability: dev` and `prefer-stable: true` to the composer.json of both repository A and the private/package but that changes nothing. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Please post the `composer.json` contents of `Repository A`, assuming it is your root package. The private/package/composer.json minimum-stability setting should technically be ignored by composer, since [`minimum-stability`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) applies to the [root-package only](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#root-package), except when using `composer install/update` from private/package as the root.

Comment: You could execute `composer why-not mollie/mollie-api-php:^2.0` and it may show you what is blocking the installation. One possibility is that in RepoA you have a conflicting version (like `^1`) already required.

Comment: looks like dependency problem. did you require mollie?

composer require mollie/mollie-api-php

also you can check requeriments with

composer check-platform-reqs

Comment: Does using `--with-all-dependencies` switch changes anything? `composer update --with-all-dependencies private/package`.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasK. ! Never saw this command, it helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm a bit ashamed of myself. For some reason there was a `^1.9` require in repository A. (Only in the one repository I was testing of the many repositories I maintain)

The following command instantly pointed me in the right direction:

```
composer why-not mollie/mollie-api-php:^2.0
```